# Looping over rows of a dataframe conditionally

Tags: r, function, dataframe, loops, lapply

My looping structure below works great. However, if we had: `m = data.frame(po = c(1,2,1,2), ou = rep(1,4))` and `input = rev(expand.grid(ou = seq_len(max(m$ou)), po = seq_len(max(m$po))))` and I expected the same output as now (i.e., a list of two elements),

then, how should the `lapply(input, ...` change?

```
m = list(A = data.frame(po = c(1,2,1,2), ou = rep(1,4)))
# if: `m = data.frame(po = c(1,2,1,2), ou = rep(1,4))`

input <- lapply(m, function(i) rev(expand.grid(ou = seq_len(max(i$ou)),
 po = seq_len(max(i$po)))))

# if: `input = rev(expand.grid(ou = seq_len(max(m$ou)), po = seq_len(max(m$po))))`

lapply(input, function(inp) Map(function(p, o)  ## Then, how should this change?
  do.call(rbind, lapply(m, function(m1)
    m1[m1$po == p & m1$ou == o, , drop = FALSE])), inp$po, inp$ou))

#==== Current & Desired Output:
#$A
#$A[[1]]
    po ou
A.1  1  1
A.3  1  1

#$A[[2]]
    po ou
A.2  2  1
A.4  2  1
```

Comment: I'm a little confused what you are asking. What is the change to the input that would require you to change the lapply statement?

Comment: Aha OK in that case just wrap it as `lapply(list(input), ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see the minimal amount of change to your code required to return the same input in the alternative case is to wrap both `input` and `m` in the function `list()` so that they are both lists of length 1 with that single element being a data frame. Data frames are themselves lists (each column of the data frame is an element of the list). Because of this, if you do not wrap the data frames in `list()`,  the `lapply` statement will try to iterate over the columns of the data frame and fail.

```
m <- data.frame(po = c(1,2,1,2), ou = rep(1,4))

input <- rev(expand.grid(ou = seq_len(max(m2$ou)), po = seq_len(max(m2$po))))

lapply(list(input), function(inp) Map(function(p, o)  ## How should this change?
  do.call(rbind, lapply(list(m), function(m1)
    m1[m1$po == p & m1$ou == o, , drop = FALSE])), inp$po, inp$ou))
```

Comment: Do you think we can decrease one level of listing in the output? So, we have `new_output = list(data.frame(po=c(1,1),ou=c(1,1)), data.frame(po=c(2,2),ou=c(1,1)))`

Comment: Yes, you can "flatten" the output by 1 level by calling `unlist(output, recursive = FALSE)`

Comment: But nothing else can be done to directly get the "flattened" output directly from the `lapply()` and `Map()` calls, right?

Comment: Some trick might be possible with `vapply()` but I'm not sure